# Difference between munach legarmei revii and gershayim revii

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation

Is there any grammatical difference between a munach legarmei before a revii and a gershayim before a revii?

For example, the first words in [Bamidbar 16:17](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0416.htm) and 16:18 are very similar (וקחו/ויקחו איש מחתתו), but one has a munach legarmei and one has a gershayim.  ויקחו has an extra syllable, but it's not obvious to me why (or if) that causes this change.

If there's no grammatical reason, I'd accept a drash explanation, but preferably it should be simple enough that I can remember it and apply it when I'm leining, if necessary.  Also, I'm looking for a general explanation, not something specific to these pesukim in Korach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R. [Mordechai Breuer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Breuer) in his *Ta'amei HaMikra* ([2:39](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMsQf.jpg)) says we don't know a fixed rule for when Munach-Legarmeih or Gershayim should serve when preceding a Revi'i, but he does note (fn. 23), using your example, a noticeable preference for Munach-Legarmeih to serve on short words.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but thanks

Comment: So that's why the gershayim in כִּ֞י בְּחֹ֣דֶשׁ הָֽאָבִ֗יב always sounded weird to me!  I couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: page 4 of http://www.jstor.org/stable/24347436